# Bash script with inotifywait executes twice before closing

Tags: bash, shell, centos, inotify

Hello everyone,

```
    #!/bin/sh
    inotifywait -e move,create /home/importantdirectory|
    while read path action file;
    do
       *do something here*
    done
```

I have this script running to watch the directory and then sends an email notification. When I run it, it seems to run twice, as in I receive the email notification twice. I removed the email notification code and put some simple echos inside. Still I get it 2 times. How can I see if this folder is being watched more than once. I was running it **nohup ./execscript > /dev/null 2>&1 &**
I shutdown the script and ran it **./execscript** and I indeed see it execute once and then seconds later a 2nd time before its done. Also can I see if the number of watches on that directory and the scripts watching it?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Edit: actually, I noticed in my command log that I have run nohup ./execscript > /dev/null 2>&1 & multiple times. could the same script be running more than once if you issue the command above ?

Comment: Have you checked `ps` to see how many copies of your script are running?

Comment: I checked with ps -aux | grep "process" and it was indeed running more then one copy. I did not know that running the same script another time would start another instance of it. I thought it would overwrite it. Such a simple thing, thank you